# Javascript callback method is not called?

Tags: javascript, callback

I am trying to create a reusable Header object with a right button. I'm having problems on my callback method on the button click. It's never called.

My object:

```
myHeader:function(params)   
{       
    opt = {
        title: "Title",  //header tittle
        fs: PrecApp.DEFAULT_HEADER_FONTSIZE, //font size
        ignoreStack :true, //ignore stack
        height: "70", //header height
        rightButton: {
            show :false, //show right button
            background: "none", //background for right button
            text: "Button", //text for right button
            width: "auto",
            height:"auto",              
            color:"black",
            fontize:1,
            extraCss: null,
            onClick:function(){}
        }
    }
for (i in params) opt[i] = params[i];

    if (opt.rightButton.show){
        var right = $("#header .right");            
        right.click(opt.rightButton.onClick);           

    }       
}
```

And in my html :

```
function updateLayout(){
                PrecAppComponents.myHeader({
                    title:"My Title",
                    fs:1.5,
                    height:50,
                    rightButton:{
                        show:true,
                        background:"#ffff00",
                        text:"Right",
                        width:70,
                        height:30,
                        fontsize:1.1,
                        extraCss: {"float":"left", "font-size":"0.5em"},
                        onClick: PrecAppComponents.toggleDarkOverlay(true)

                    }
}
```

Everything else is working fine. If i replace

```
right.click(opt.rightButton.onClick);
```

with

```
 right.click(function(
  console.log("clicked")
));
```

It works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How can you tell it isn't being called? `function(){}` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Watch out for `this`. If your `onClick` function (which I'm assuming you make non-trivial elsewhere in your code) uses `this`, it will not be set to `opt.rightButton` unless you do so explicitly (e.g. using `bind`).

Comment: I guess with `for (i in params) opt[i] = params[i];` he tries to extend `opt` with `params`.

Comment: In the html when i create my header, I am overriding all the options including the onClick: PrecAppComponents.toggleDarkOverlay(true)

Comment: Looks like your desired onClick is *calling* a function, not returning one.

Comment: Provide an example of your params object. For some reason `onClick` does not get overwritten.

Comment: @numbers1311407 if i do that i get an error saying  property 'onClick' is not a function. I'll put this in jsfiddle and post here in a few mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your onClick option is calling a function.  Unless that call is returning another function, this won't work:

```
onClick: PrecAppComponents.toggleDarkOverlay(true)
```

You'd have to change it to something like:

```
onClick: function() {
  PrecAppComponents.toggleDarkOverlay(true);
}

// or with bind, perhaps

onClick: PrecAppComponents.toggleDarkOverlay.bind(PrecAppComponents, true);
```

Comment: NAILED! If surround with the anonymous function in the HTML override it works as a charm! Thanks a lot! I'm still learning this js tricks! I'll accept your answer in 5 mins  as soon as SO lets me :).

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulation in an anonymous function:

```
right.click(function(){opt.rightButton.onClick();});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `PrecAppComponents.toggleDarkOverlay(true)` does not *return a function* to be called as an event handler - you execute it immediately. You will need to use

```
function(e) {
    PrecAppComponents.toggleDarkOverlay(true);
}
```

or

```
PrecAppComponents.toggleDarkOverlay.bind(PrecAppComponents, true)
```